# Paypal redirect on registration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal

I need to redirect to PaypalAgreement after successfull registration. I have two type of user free and paid when somebody tries to register as paid redirect to Paypal Payment gateway

```
$plan_id = 'P-4C095357DP980872FT2QOCTA';
$agreement = new PaypalAgreement();
$agreement->create($plan_id);


 class PaypalAgreement extends Paypal
{
public function create($id) {

    return redirect($this->Agreement($id));
}

protected function Agreement($id): string
{
    $agreement = new Agreement();
    $agreement->setName('Base Agreement')
        ->setDescription('Basic Agreement')
        ->setStartDate('2019-06-17T9:45:04Z');
    $plan = $this->Plan($id);
    $agreement->setPlan($plan);
    $payer = $this->Payer();
    $agreement->setPayer($payer);
    $ShippingAddress = $this->ShippingAddress();
    $agreement->setShippingAddress($ShippingAddress);
    $agreement = $agreement->create($this->apiContext);

    return $agreement->getApprovalLink();
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in